# The semantical change of сарай - "saráj" (rus., ukr.) vs. sister and donor languages: pl. 'seraj', srb-cro. 'saraj'

Tags: etymology, semantics, historical-linguistics, language-change, slavic-languages

[image: pictured a 'Saray', Turkish for palace]

Much like (eng.) *saray*, the words derive themselves from Ottoman Turkish latinized: *saray* ("palace", "mansion", "castle"), which itself is derived from Persian سرای ("hall", "dwelling", "mansion", "palace", "seraglio")

The words don't deviate much from one another, generally referring to an Ottoman Turkish palace or a seraglio in the context harem of palaces. The city of Sarajevo derives itself from this.

Example:

Croatian: ((HJP - "Croatian Language Portal" - hjp.znanje.hr))

**Noun:**

**saraj** *m. inan.*

1. Every grand palace, a court for Sultans, Viziers, and other high officials.
2. Harem ((seraglio))
3. ((Metonymy)) Things belonging to a Sultan.

However, if we take a look at the Russian definition:

Russian ((en.wiktionary)):

[image: picture of a shed]

**Noun:**

**сара́й** (saráj) *m. inan.*

1. shed, storage building (small wooden construction)
2. uncomfortable, untidy room, pigsty

It's almost as if it were an intentional and ironic mistranslation of the original word. Completely polarized meanings.

**Question:**

How and when did this change occur? Was it politically motivated during Russo-Turkish conflicts? Or maybe a pidgin word that Russian-based merchants picked up from Middle Eastern trade? Though, would be interesting to see how that came about.

Comment: Can you check the etymology of the Russian and Ukrainian words? Maybe they are loaned directly from Iranian (Scythian or Ossetian are possible donor languages) with a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Both South Slavic and East Slavic borrowed this Persian word via Turkic languages, but separately - ie long after the Slavic languages branched.

It is only in East Slavic that the Russian meaning occurs - not in Iranic, not in Turkic nor in South Slavic.

If we can observe a tendency in Russian borrowings from Turkic, I would ascribe it less to conflict - there were Russian conflicts with the French and Germans too, and the South Slavs had plenty of conflict with the Ottomans - than to Russia's colonial relationship with the Caucasus and Asia generally.

> Происходит от перс. sarāi, sarā «дворец». Перс. слово восходит к др.-ир. *srāða-, которое родственно готск. hrōt «крыша». К тому же источнику через посредство франц. sérail следует возводить и сера́й, сера́ль. Русск. слово заимств. через тюркск.; ср.: тур., кыпч., уйг., тат. sаrаi «дом; дворец; каравансарай; комната для жилья; стойло; тележный сарай». Сюда же Сара́й — город на нижней Волге (Лаврентьевск. летоп. под 1261 г.), ср.-греч. Σαράγιον (ХIV--ХV в.).

See also: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_terms_derived_from_Turkic_languages

Comment: I'm not at all sure *бардак* is Turkic, rather than an expressively shortened and suffixed *бордель*.

Comment: You may be right.  I find claims of both etymologies, and a third one (French *barda*).

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly similar to the case of the borrowing of the French word *château* into Brazilian Portuguese. In French, *château* means castle; in Portuguese, *chatô* means humble residence - more like a bachelor's little flat than like the picture you posted, but still the irony is perceptible.

In this case, I think, there are two factors that made possible for the import semantically shift in such way: first, Portuguese already had a word for castle, *castelo*; second, castles are not a part of the Brazilian landscape. So there would be no need to import a word for something that, 1. already had a name; and 2. wasn't that important to really need a new name.

Perhaps there are similar issues considering these words in Russian and Serbo-Croat; perhaps the palace culture in the Balkans coincided with Ottoman domination, while Russia developed palaces of its own, or in the context of German or French influence, and so coined a local word for palace, or imported it from Western Europe, so when "saraj" was imported, the semantic slot for "palace" was already occupied?

Comment: "while Russia developed palaces of its own, or in the context of German or French influence, and so coined a local word for palace, or imported it from Western Europe, so when "saraj" was imported, the semantic slot for "palace" was already occupied?"  Could well be the case - there are words like "терем", "палаты(полаты)", which, I believe, existed in (old) Russian long before the "сарай" was borrowed. [No proof found yet, sorry.]

Comment: In modern Russian the word for palace is "dvorets". There were ancient word "palata" and "terem". Terem is a Greek borrowing, "palata" is evidently a cognate to "palace", also a borrowing, ultimately from Latin. Now Russian uses a Slavic word.